# jquery and @Html.Label

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The problem i'm having is though it's passing the function Username, it`s not displaying the * after passing the

```
$("#Name").text("*");  In debug mode in Mozilla, it displays undefined! What is wrong or what have I missed?
```

I have `@Html.Label("Name", "")` and

```
$('#changePassword').click(function () {
               if (Username()) {
                   $("#changePassword").dialog('open');
                   return false;
               }
           });

 function Username() {
           if ($("#Name").val() == "") {
               $("#Name").text("*");
               return false;
           }
           else {
               return true;
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write `@Html.Label("Name", "")` no HTML is generated which is a bit strange but this is how this helper is implemented. `@Html.Label("Name", " ")` the following HTML will be generated:

```
<label for="Name"> </label>
```

Notice that there is no id. So you cannot reference the label with `$('#Name')`. You need to use the following:

```
$('label[for=Name]').html('*');
```

Comment: Indeed I find it strange. I did the following:
              @Html.Label("Name", "Name")
             @Html.Label("namePrompt", "")
             @Html.Label("", "nameprompt")
             @Html.Label("nameprompt", "nameprompt") and the following are the HTML generated  <label for="Name">Name</label>
50
51 <label for="">nameprompt</label>
52 <label for="nameprompt">nameprompt</label> I don`t need any text in the label, but with @Html.Label("Name", ""), no HTML tag is being generated!

Comment: the @HTml.Label("Name", "") isn`t generating any HTML tag! Is that working for you?

Comment: @user281180, yes that's exactly what I said in my answer. Try using `@HTml.Label("Name", " ")`. Notice the space.

Comment: Thanks, didn`t notice the space.  Stupid me!